# Classic ASP Check if 1 minute has passed if so trigger command

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to check the current time VS the database time and display a message.
This is my second attempt but it's not working correctly, as you can see below, I am doing something wrong. Please help.

Thanks.

```
   <%
    Function ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(input_datetime) 'As String
        Dim d : d = CDate(input_datetime)
        ConvertToUnixTimeStamp = CStr(DateDiff("s", "01/01/2018 00:00:00", d))
    End Function


    'Response.write ("<BR><BR>Current Time Now: ") & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now)


    time_from_db = 11293015 + 60 'This would be the time from the database. It is generated using ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) + 60

    Response.write "Current Time: " & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) & "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "Time from DB: " & time_from_db & "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "Update DB with this time (Added 1 minute): " & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) + 60 & "<BR><BR>"


    If ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) > time_from_db then 
        Response.write("<BR>Current Time is Greaten then DB")
    else
        Response.write("<BR>DB Time is Newer then Current Time")
    end if

    %>
```

Comment: Wont `FormatNumber(DB_Heart_Beat) > FormatNumber(DB_Heart_Beat)` always be false as your comparing the same value?

Comment: @PeterVC sorry that was a typo. I fixed it but still the issue is there. Thanks

Comment: Have you printed out the values of `FormatNumber(Current_Heart_Beat)` and `FormatNumber(DB_Heart_Beat)` ?

Comment: @PeterVC Yes, it's 511,201,881,417.00>59,201,832,042.00

Comment: @PeterVC I think the issue is that there is a 0 missing from the date 59,201,832,042.00 maybe it should be 509,201,832,042.00 ?.. but how do I add a zero if the day is single digit ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at DateDiff instead of the technique you are currently using.

Comment: Please post the actual datetime string you get from the database? Much easier to do this calculation with actual datetime types.

Comment: @Jacob M. I get what I save from the ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now)  example: 11293015. That is what time_from_db also retrieves from the database

Comment: Also, is no one going to point out that a [Unix Epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is number of seconds since 01 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (or in ISO 8609 terms - 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) not 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) > time_from_db then
```

this will never return true, as your function is converting the time to a STRING, and a string cannot be greater than another string.

I made some minor changes in your code, mainly explicitly converting variables into their data type (ex: CInt, CStr, etc).

```
<%
    Function ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(input_datetime) 'As String
        Dim d : d = CDate(input_datetime)
        ConvertToUnixTimeStamp = DateDiff("s", "01/01/2018 00:00:00", d)
    End Function


    'Response.write ("<BR><BR>Current Time Now: ") & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now)


    time_from_db = 11293015 + 60 'This would be the time from the database. It is generated using ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) + 60

    Response.write "Current Time: " & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) & "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "Time from DB: " & time_from_db & "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "<BR><BR>"
    Response.write "Update DB with this time (Added 1 minute): " & ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) + 60 & "<BR><BR>"


    If CInt( ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) ) > time_from_db then 
        Response.write("<BR>Current Time is Greaten then DB")
    else
        Response.write("<BR>DB Time is Newer then Current Time")
    end if

    %>
```

Comment: Hi, I get an error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006'

Overflow: 'CInt' line 19:     If CInt( ConvertToUnixTimeStamp(Now) ) > time_from_db then

Comment: use CLng in place of CInt

Comment: I assume this worked? just curious more than anything else :)